# .NET Runtime Optimization Service is missing

Tags: .net, ngen

I am currently developing software which I would like while the software is installing, it can create the native images for the software in the background.

I am thinking of using NGEN and also set the process priority to low because I don't want it to consume 100% CPU. But I found out the ".NET Runtime  Optimization Service" is actually missing from the "Services" on my computer. So NGEN won't actually continue all my process even when the computer is in "idle".

I just wonder is there any way I can re-register the service or are there any solutions for it?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'll add a bounty for this question so it might get some attention.

Comment: It is supposed to be missing.  The service implemented by mscorsvw.exe is automatically activated by the ngen.exe install command.  The only decent way to ensure it got the job done is to run ngen.exe queue status.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: 4.7.1. If the service is missing then the queue never executes @HansPassant this means the queue is completely useless on some machines. If the service exists on your machine can you take a screenshot?

Comment: @rolls On my machine I have only `.NET Runtime Optimization Service v2.0.50727_X86` for old .NET 2.0/3.5 versions, for .NET 4 there a couple of scheduled tasks

Comment: This is the service that is missing from a majority of machines we install our application on. This is the service we want to figure out how to reinstall or activate.

Answer (score 2):

I've checked the NGEN service on my Win10 machine and found only `.NET Runtime Optimization Service v2.0.50727_X86` for old .NET 2.0/3.5, there is no service for .NET 4.x. But I found a couple of scheduled tasks in **Task Scheduler Library/Microsoft/Windows/.NET Framework**

[image]

[This article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/wondering-why-mscorsvw-exe-has-high-cpu-usage-you-can-speed-it-up/) and [optimization script](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/tools/DrainNGENQueue/DrainNGenQueue.wsf) will help to figure the problem out. It seems, that for Win8 and later MS developers are using the task instead of service to run queued native image generation

```
var drainAppStoreQueue = function () {
        var schTasks = wsh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%\\System32\\schtasks.exe");
        var arguments = "/run /Tn \"\\Microsoft\\Windows\\.NET Framework\\.NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319";
        runToCompletion(schTasks, arguments + "\"", true);

        if (is64bit)
            runToCompletion(schTasks, arguments + " 64\"", true);
    }

    drainNGenQueue(isV4Installed ? "v4.0.30319" : "v2.0.50727");

    if (isOSWin8OrLater) {
        drainAppStoreQueue();
    }
```

I've tried to get a status of ngen service for both x86/x64 .NET Framework version and it reports

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>ngen queue status
>
> Microsoft (R) CLR Native Image Generator - Version 4.8.3752.0
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Service name is: .NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319 The .NET Runtime
>   Optimization Service is stopped.

As I understood, it'll start when action is queued for the scheduled execution. According to ngen [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ngen-exe-native-image-generator), you have a two options:

1. Run `ngen install [assemblyName | assemblyPath]` to install the
   assemblies immediately and synchronously (and will take a time, but
   you run it directly)
2. Or specify the `/queue[:{1|2|3}]`, to make the image generation is scheduled (immediately or in idle time, depending on priority)

You can also test that tasks above are working by running `ngen update /queue`. Per documentation

> If /queue is specified, the updates are queued for the native image
>   service. Updates are always scheduled at priority 3, so they run when
>   the computer is idle.

In my machine this command set the status of `.NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319` task to Queued and updates Last Run Time. You can always excute all scheduled actions synchronously by invoking `ngen executeQueuedItems`

Comment: Thanks, a scheduled task rather than a service. Huh. Never thought of that (nor did the person writing the docs).

Comment: This is the service that is missing from the majority of machines we install our application on. Hence when we specify /queue they never execute. These machines all have .net 4.7.1 installed. If .NET Runtime Optimization Service v2.0.50727_X86 is missing, then /queue does not work no matter how many restarts you do.

Comment: The task you mention does not seem to run either on these machines.

Comment: @rolls Please, read the answer above carefully:) `.NET Runtime Optimization Service v2.0.50727_X86` is only for old .NET 2/3.5, it doesn't exist on machines with .NET 4.  .NET Framework 4.7.1 is an in-place update to the Microsoft .NET Framework 4, 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, and 4.7 according [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56116) They are sharing the same CLR v4.0.30319 runtime

Comment: I've checked a multiple machines with .NET 4.5 and .NET 4.6.2 installed, the NGEN tasks are present. Please, check the service status by invoking `ngen queue status` and `ngen update /queue`

Comment: Hi Pavel, thanks for your reply. I am trying to implement the ngen as Schedule Task and I am testing this line of code
"schtasks /create /TN "testing" /TR ngen install ***.dll" /ST 17:21 /SC ONCE"
which will register the task and should call "ngen install ..." when its 17.21(or anytime we specified), but ngen doesnt seem to get called properly. Do you have any ideas?. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Hi @ScottTan Which .NET version are you using? What is not working, task itself or `ngen`? Did you try to run task manually? Did you try to run built-in tasks?

Comment: 4.7.1, i tried run the command i put in "/tr" to separate command prompt window, ngen task does run. my current issue is that, the schtask did get called but it didnt run the command in /tr

Comment: @ScottTan it seems to be an issue with `schtasks`, rather then with `ngen`. According to docs [`/tr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks#tr-taskrun) expects the fully qualified path, it can be an issue

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski yes, i can make the schtask run properly now with "/RL HIGHEST" flag defined. But now issue is, i would like the task run only once when the computer in idle and delete itself after it runs. I have searched over the internet but cannot find any solutions, would you have any ideas on that? thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what version of .net you are using, however ngen is not always doing the same on all Maschine's you would like to deploy to.

For that reason MS has altered the compiler and project structure. A small extract from my project shows this have a look at the **PublishReadyToRun** as this **PublishTrimmed** does what NGEN used to do, making a single file helps by setting **PublishSingleFile** to true would help if you like to deployment easy as it makes 1 huge exe and removes all dll's.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="mscorlib" />
    <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="System" />
    <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="System.IO" />
    <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="System.Threading.Tasks" />
  </ItemGroup>
…
</Project>
```

Have a look at Mr [Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingATinyNETCore30EntirelySelfcontainedSingleExecutable.aspx) blog on this.

One of the first things I noticed when I used it  is that I had a FileNotFound exception when the exe loaded the dependencies. You can fix this by looking at the name of the file missing that basically got removed by the optimisation and add them to the TrimmerRootAssembly like I did in the sample. After adding those 4 I had no more issues.

**NGEN**
Client machines that do not have NGEN or the "wrong" one would need to have the .NET Framework SDK installed (why would a user have a SDK/ Software Development Kit installed...)

if that file is missing (you can test for it using the path using something like this:

```
Directory.GetFiles($@"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows)}\Microsoft.NET\Framework\","ngen.exe",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

If that returns no file you can pop a message for the user to download and install the "right sdk" after that you can continue with your optimisation strategy using the command line for ngen.exe

LOW priority
An easy trick to start your application in a lower thread priority is by starting it using the START command.
[image]

Comment: The issue we have is the net optimisation runtime service is missing from the list of services. Hence if you set priority to 3 (idle) it never actually runs.

Comment: ReadyToRun is something completely different. It's only used in *.NET Core 3*.

Comment: We are using net 471 so we can't use that.

Comment: ngen itself isn't missing from the PC, just the service that is meant to run at idle is missing from the service manager. So if we use ngen /queue to 3 (idle) it never ever runs. We are already running ngen as low priority, but if the user shuts the PC down before it finishes, then we have no way of knowing. The service is the correct method, however the service seems to be unregistered on several machines we have tried.